# Why is this bash script running over and over and over?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

This script has somehow gotten stuck in a loop where it is starting over and over and over.

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage  decimator.sh "$1" "$2"
echo $1
echo $2
bin/decimator.sh --pdfinfile "$1" --outdir scr --tldr "$2"
```

Here is the history where it got started.

```
 1997  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 1998  git pull
 1999  lart ~/pagekicker-community/test/data/
 2000  cp ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf ~/pagekicker-community/test/data .
 2001  cp ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf ~/pagekicker-community/test/data/.
 2002  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2003  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2004  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2005  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2006  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2007  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2008  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2009  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2010  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2011  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
 2012  ../test/decimator-test.sh ../test/data/Altmetrics_for_LibrariansAltmetric.pdf "dumbing down Altmetrics"
```

I did a system restart and I did ps aux | grep test to see if the process is there. No joy.

It's still doing it, a thousand history lines later...

Comment: We're not going to be able to guess based on the three line script you posted. See [mcve] for pointers on including enough information to make your question answerable.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: It's as if the line is being typed into the command line over and over again. I am not doing it!  It should have run once and then stopped.

Comment: It's really irritating to get minus points for a legitimate question.

Comment: @FredZimmermann: The question is legitimate, but the information you provided is not up to the point. There is obviously nothing in your script, which can show this behaviour. The real interesting point are the repeating entries in the history file which you posted. Maybe something in bin/decimator.sh (or some subordinate script of this) not only reads and executes the history entry, but also adds the freshly executed  line back in the history (perhaps because the shell is explicitly set to interactive). If you now run the command twices in succession, does it start all over with the looping?

Comment: Given as there's no reproducer here, and no information retained to allow an investigation to take place (no sysdig or strace or `set -x` tracking, for instance), this question is unlikely to be useful to others in its current state.

Comment: If you *can* reproduce it, btw, `set -x` -- or `bash -x yourscript` -- is very, very much your friend. (I wouldn't be surprised if it showed a DEBUG trap or such -- define `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'` to make `set -x` logs more helpful, if the trap -- or other responsible hook -- is calling code defined in a script).

Answer (score 1):

After reasoning that the problem seemed to be that history was feeding into the command line in a loop and finding [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191999/how-to-clear-bash-history-completely)

I ran:

```
history -c
history -w
```

That fixed the problem. I am still not sure how it got started.

Comment: I understand that!